# I want to to disallow everything except ssh, e-mail, and http

Tags: server, ssh, apache2, ufw, debian

If I use:

```
sudo ufw default deny incoming
sudo ufw default allow outgoing
sudo ufw allow ssh
sudo ufw allow http
    ...etc
sudo ufw enable
```

To block the world from entering my website execpt certain ip's, why am I still getting a lot of ip's in my apache2 access log?

Comment: apache logs blokd requests also.

Comment: @petep what do you mean? If UFW blocks traffic, it won't reach Apache.

Comment: Dan, you are telling us you have _opened_ the ports to Apache, and now are surprised to see traffic coming in? What were you expecting?

Comment: In other words, you allowed http.

Comment: look for 400 error codes in apache log

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You have confused the terms IP and port. In addition to the port you want, you need to specify the IPs.

In your example, `sudo ufw allow http` opened the HTTP ***port*** (port 80) for ***any IP***. Anyway, you need to `sudo ufw delete` the rule number of the HTTP rule you got from `sudo ufw status numbered`. To delete everything, run `sudo ufw reset`.

Then you would need to run `sudo ufw allow proto tcp from AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD to any port 80` for HTTP, where AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD is the certain IP you want. Likewise for SSH (port 22).

If you would like to add multiple IPs, run that command multiple times. A more advanced topic is CIDR, where there is a `/XX` at the end. If you understand it, you can use syntax of the style `AAA.BBB.CCC.0/24`.

For email, I will either guess or suggest that you use a cloud email provider. In that case, you don't need to add any rules for email because it is an outgoing connection.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to this blocking stuff.  I'm using Debian 12 with UFW and Fail2ban (both of the lastest verison).  Currently right now I have :  80/tcp, 443/tcp,3389/tcp,WWW Full action = ALLOW from = Anywhere.

Comment: Debian unfortunately is [off-topic on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Dan You have Ubuntu server in 2022. Ubuntu is simpler than Debian. I also recommend that you find and take an online course / tutorial on computer networking to help you establish the prerequisite knowledge that is the distinction between an IP and a port

Comment: @Daniel T  Thank you for your advise on this topic.  I know the differences between an ip address (192.168.1.1) and a port (80/tcp).  I read the topic of an early post, followed the directions to the "T", and I'm still getting hackers from all over.

Comment: If you followed my post, you would not get hackers from all over in your apache2 log. You would only see the few aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd ip addresses that you specifically allowed there. You should see the hackers being blocked by ufw in dmesg. Make sure you remove your original rules before you add the new ones.